# Building document classifier based on keywords, what would be the steps?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, model-selection, classifier

I have a requirement of classifying documents(`.doc` files) based on the profiles. I have a `csv` file with data:

```
label          keyWords
Web developer  ["html","css","php"]
Developer      ["core","java","python"]
Embedded Dev   ["ARM", "CORTEX", "C"]
```

Now I want to classify the `.doc` files.

Also please do tell me what `model` to use ? or broad steps for proceeding (like building dataframe-> then splitting data and so on...)

**EDIT:**
Any pointers on how to proceed with document classifier ?

Comment: Someone with appropriate reputation points, please add document-classifier tag.

Comment: It is just a classification problem based on whatever text you have available. But how will you extract keywords from documents?

Comment: I have the keywords already in a `csv` file as shown above. I want to know how to classify the `.doc` files now as according to the words found in them using a classifier.

Comment: Would really be helpful, if you upvote the question so it can be answered.

Comment: you can start with a simple bag-of-words representation of your documents (which are just vectors). use the python collections.Counter or the appropriate [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/) tool to perform it.

Comment: ok great will try that and let you know @manu-h but how to make a dataset out of `.doc` files ?

Comment: @Rex5 you may use any tool extracting plain text (maybe [tika](https://www.nltk.org/)?) Don't hesitate to precise your question when you have played a little with all those tools and are stuck again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got your email...

Built this example repository for ya:
https://github.com/dancrew32/resume_classifer/

If you go through the notebook, I outlined the process of setting up labels, different folders for different kinds of resumes, loading them up, vectorizing text, classifying using logistic regression.

https://github.com/dancrew32/resume_classifer/blob/master/Resume%20Doc%20Classifier.ipynb

Let me know if you have any questions.

P.S. Never adding a skip button ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @tester it really mean a lot for people starting with ML. For others inquisitive of 'skip' button check tester's site.

Comment: Hi tester, how can I make use of the `keyWords` column ? I mean in the notebook we aren't using that ?